# How was the cameraman removed from the mirrors in the elevator scene?

Tags: effects, cinematography, shattered

In the movie [Shattered](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0489664/) (aka *Butterfly on a wheel*), at about the 7th minute, Neil Randall (Gerard Butler) is going up an elevator, with another person in it.

[image]

From the angle of the shot, I am 100% certain that the camera man (or at least the camera) should have been seen in the mirrors.

How come they aren't? Was there an effect used?

Comment: don't have time to write an elaborate answer with all the possible ways they could've shot this scene (hence the comment), but the first thing that comes to mind is using the "one-way mirror" technique. I haven't seen this one, so not sure how the cameras move, if they do, or how many different angles are used etc. But unless the camera(s) pans around it's not that difficult to set up. Just looking at the screenshot it could be as simple as a mirror and then, on the opposite side, glass with a camera behind it

Comment: x2. The one that comes immediately to mind is the mirrored glass used in police interrogation rooms. Even the panning around could be done with 3 sides of one way mirrors like that.